# MySQL Stored Procedure not outputting correct value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This has to be simple and I am just missing it.  I am trying to run a stored procedure like this;

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Testing$$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `Testing`(out d varchar(10))
BEGIN
  select @v1 =  'Value 1';
  select @v2 =  'Value 2';
  select @v3 =  'Value 3';

  set d = @v1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;


call Testing(@d);
select d;
```

The problem is that when runs it returns

[image]

This makes no sense to me.  Sorry for the simple question trying to convert a MS SQL DB to MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have tested @d is not any variable in your code which you have used to take output value from procedure.

but your last **select @v3 = 'Value 3'**  inside procedure is working as an output to console.
as you can see output is null but the column name is **select @v3 = 'Value 3'** not output of the procedure in your output window.

Hope it is cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql is a bit quirky in SELECT,this statement

```
select @v1 =  'Value 1';
```

is in fact,a comparison;it compares @v1 which is by default NULL to `value 1`,which will return null.If you want to assign a value use :=

```
select @v1 :=  'Value 1';
```

Or,use SET;

```
SET @v1 =  'Value 1';
```